# Число с плавающей точкой не выводится с нужной точностью в с++

Tags: c++, вывод, float, double, форматирование

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long double a = 10 / 3.0;
    std::cout << a <<std::endl;
    printf("%Lf\n", a);
}
    /*  вывод:
          3.33333
          3.333333
    */
```

Никак не могу понять, куда деваются тройки после запятой, тип long double должен выдавать куда бОльшую точность. Причем цифр недостает и при выводе с помощью cout, и при выводе с помощью printf. И по какой причине количество цифр после запятой различается при разных способах вывода?

Comment: Не пробовали поставить что-то типа `printf("%.15Lf\n", a);`?

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Это просто дефолтные настройки форматтеров того или иного способа вывода. По умолчанию выводится сколько-то цифр после запятой. Надо другой формат - указываете конкретный формат.

Comment: @CrazyElf Понятно, спасибо за пояснение

Answer (score 3):

Указывайте точность для вывода - например, для вывода 15 знаков после запятой это выглядит [так](https://ideone.com/8Eepop):

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(15) << a <<std::endl;
printf("%.15Lf\n", a);
```

Если не указывать ничего - выводятся стандартные 6 знаков.

Comment: Хорошо бы пояснить - а что вообще происходит, если точность не указывать